# How to add values to listbox?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have Datatable collected with my Column Names.. I want to add them in listbox.. Many column are there.. So need to use For each how can i achieve this

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.Net?

Answer (score 1):

using `DisplayMember and ValueMember`

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

// 1. set DisplayMember and ValueMember
lbSiteCode.DisplayMember = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName;
lbSiteCode.ValueMember = dt.Columns[1].ColumnName;
// 2. set DataSource
lbSiteCode.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataColumnCollection columns = ds.Tables[0].Columns;
foreach (DataColumn column in columns)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(column.ColumnName);
}
```

Comment: @Shiny: You're asking how to add the columns to a ListBox.